# Android ksoap2 javadoc - how to download

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to download the javadoc for ksoap2-android 2.5.6 here:

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/source/browse/#svn%2Fm2-repo%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fcode%2Fksoap2-android%2Fksoap2-android-assembly%2F2.5.6%253Fstate%253Dclosed

but the file after download only contains the manifest. I'm following the directions on the wiki page for "How To Use":
"To download a file from there, right click on "View raw file" and select "Save Link as" (this label differs for different browsers) and you will get the full jar downloaded."

I've tried this with multiple browsers.

Does anyone know where/how to get the ksoap2-android javadoc?

Answer (score 1):

Well apparently "assembly" didn't went well for javadoc and resulted empty file. You can download base javadoc from ksoap2-base folder, but not from ksoap2-android-assembly:
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-base/2.5.7/ksoap2-base-2.5.7-javadoc.jar but it will contain only docs for "base" ksoap2 classes - which does good job, as this jar is most of "assembly" jar.

This is most recent version for the day of writing.